# How to pass byte slice between go routines using channels

Tags: go, slice, channel

I have a function that reads data from a `source` and send them to `destination`. Source and destination could be anything, lets say for this example source is database (any `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`...) and destination is `distributed Q` (any... `ActiveMQ`, `Kafka`). Messages are stored in bytes.

This is main function. idea is it will spin a new go routine and will wait for messages to be returned for future processing.

```
type Message []byte

func (p *ProcessorService) Continue(dictId int) {
    level.Info(p.logger).Log("process", "message", "dictId", dictId)
    retrieved := make(chan Message)

    go func() {
        err := p.src.Read(retrieved, strconv.Itoa(p.dictId))
        if err != nil {
            level.Error(p.logger).Log("process", "read", "message", "err", err)
        }
    }()

    for r := range retrieved {
        go func(message Message) {
            level.Info(p.logger).Log("message", message)
            if len(message) > 0 {
                if err := p.dst.sendToQ(message); err != nil {
                    level.Error(p.logger).Log("failed", "during", "persist", "err", err)
                }
            } else {
                level.Error(p.logger).Log("failed")
            }
        }(r)
    }
}
```

and this is read function itself

```
func (s *Storage) Read(out chan<- Message, opt ...string) error {

    // I just skip some basic database read operations here
    // but idea is simple, read data from the table / file row by row and 
    // 
    for _, value := range dataFromDB {
            message, err := value.row 
            if err == nil {
                out <- message
            } else {
                errorf("Unable to get data %v", err)
                out <- make([]byte, 0)
            }
        }
    })

    close(out)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

As you can see communication done via out chan<- Message channel. 
My concern in Continue function, specifically here

```
for r := range retrieved { 
   go func(message Message) {
       // basically here message and r are pointing to the same underlying array
   }
}
```

When data received `var r` is a type of slice byte. Then it passed to `go func(message Message)` everything passed by value in go, in this case `var r` will be passed as copy to anonymous func, however it will still have a pointer to underlying slice data. I am curious if it could be a problem during `p.dst.sendToQ(message);` execution and at the same time read function will send something to `out channel` causing slice data structure to be overridden with a new information. Should I copy byte slice `r` into the new byte slice before passing to anonymous function, so underlying arrays will be different? I tested it, but couldn't really cause this behavior. Not sure if I am paranoid or have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `message` in `p.dst.sendToQ(message)` is the same slice as `value.row` when you get data from the db. So, as long as each `value.row` has a different underlying array, you should be good. So, I suggest you check the source and make sure it does not use a common byte array and keeps rewriting to it.

Comment: I tried on two objects, value.row has always different address Slice ADDRESS value.row [0xc0002b4980] , [0xc0001f6700]  but var r always same ADDRESS r [0xc0001f6140] [0xc0001f6140], I used unsafe.Pointer(&r) . which is make sense. But still it means i have to copy r? Because even if value.row return different slices var r gets overridden and used in net function Persist

Comment: `r` is a variable on the stack so its address won't change. Every new slice will overwrite `r`, which will then be passed to the goroutine as a copy. Next time `r` gets a new value, the goroutine already has its own copy.

Comment: umm, not sure I follow, does it mean I have to copy? In my understanding goroutine has it s own copy (message) of r slice but with same pointer to underlying array. So if r changes it will change a copy in goroutine, potentially sending wrong data to Persist if it didn't finish?

Comment: `r` is a slice, that is, a pointer to array, len, and cap. You pass `r` to a goroutine, and the goroutine gets a copy of that ptr,len,cap. Then `r` is assigned to another slice with a different pointer, len, cap. As long as the underlying array is different, you don't need to copy. Based on your comment earlier, the underlying array is different, so you don't need to copy.

Comment: ~oh, got it. So each time r will get a pointer to a new array with diff address to an underlying array.. but local copy of r (named message) in go routine will have a pointer to an array with previous address of previous array (copied).. hence even if r  changes local copy still contains diff address cause it is a copy.. think got it